# Excel 2013 changes the number I enter

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 2013
A cell is formatted for "Number, zero decimal places and Use 1000s separator". I type in 108000, press enter and Excel puts 1080 in the cell. There is no change to the format of the cell. This problem has recently arisen. I've been using the same spread sheet for years; never had such a problem. Adding an apostrophe before the number such as '108000 will then enter the correct number but you must enter the separator manually. The cell format remains unchanged. I've tried copying and pasting the format from another cell with no change. It appears that all the cells in my spread sheet respond the same way. Excel seems to be dividing any entry by 100.

Found my problem: Under advanced options I had set "Automatically set decimal point" on. Turn off and problem solved.

Comment: If you create a new spreadsheet does this behavior continue?

Comment: Deselect:  `File=>Options=>Advanced=>Editing Options=>Automatically insert a decimal point`